# Modify firmware of noname android tablet: first steps

Tags: android, android-firmware

I want to develop a HTML5 app to control doors, lights and other things in my garage. The frontend of will get displayed on a 24/7 turned on screen, that really only displays the app (kiosk mode). So there will be really only the app, no browser controls like back and forth button or url bar, and also no notification bar or back and home buttons of the device. Just the app.

For this I considered 2 options:

- Doing it with a raspberry PI & connect a touch screen to i
- Doint it on a dead cheap noname Android Tablet

Since the 2nd option is much more elegant from the hardware point of view (everything I need is already built in) I decided to try this first and bought a 70 USD Prestigio Tablet.

But since I'm no android dev, I'm not sure how I can even modify the stock firmware that's currently installed on the device.

As far as I can see, the bootloader is unlocked and ready for flashing a modified firmware image.

And here comes the question:
How can I get the device's currently installed firmware image? Do I have to contact the manufacturer for this or can I extract it from the device directly?
If I get the firmware image, how will I be able to modify files in it?

Or do you think I got the wrong route?

Comment: You will probably require the source for the firmware if you want to modify it. See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35376/modifying-stock-firmware. Your question might be more relevant on the Android Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find sources of firmware for your specific device. I bet manufacturer would not provide them. For Nexus devices it is easier because there is AOSP (android open source project) which gives you an opportunity to build a firmware. You can also check specific forums like 4pda.

But there is another way - to make a KIOSK mode for your device [example](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/). I'm not sure how does that fit into requirements. Also You can make your app as Launcher app and live with that :)